# What command do you use to run a bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do you do this?

This is what I got:

```
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Context
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv("token")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='prefix')


@client.command()
async def load(ctx: Context, extension):
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send("Loaded Cog")


@client.command()
async def unload(ctx: Context, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send("Unloaded Cog")


@client.command()
async def reload(ctx: Context, extension):
    client.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    client.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
    await ctx.send("Reloaded Cog")

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[0:-3]}')

client.run(token)
```

Is this right? or wrong?

I am a bigginer to coding and that type of stuff so I would really appreciate if you can help me make it better :-)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. The idea of SO is to help with code issue. If your code is working, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ If it is not, then you should describe your problem (what you did, what you expect, ...)

Answer (score 1):

you never define the token variable, but you use it in `bot.run(token)`. I suggest changing the `BOT_TOKEN` variable name you define to `token` or replace the `token` var in `bot.run(token)` to `bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)`.